# Armazenar trecho da URL - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

estou capturando determinado valor da URL através de JavaScript, porém estou com dificuldade num dado momento. Segue trecho abaixo.

```
    var url  = window.location.href;
    var page = url.split('/');
    var page = page[page.length-1];

    var arrayItens = new Array();
```

Considerando por exemplo, que a URL seja http://google.com/pagina.atual, ao executar o código acima o retorno se dará "pagina.atual". Sem novidades.

Porém, quando eu adiciono parâmetros além do "pagina.atual", ex: "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste", ele ira capturar o "pagina.atual?origem=teste". Eu preciso APENAS do "pagina.atual".

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso, seguindo o trecho citado?

Comment: Pode usar um split mesmo `"pagina.atual?origem=teste".split('?')[0]`

Comment: Kaleb, algumas das respostas resolveu a tua pergunta?

Comment: Sergio, sim. O comentário do Pedro Camara logo em seguida da postagem da pergunta ajudou bastante. Não respondi antes pela correria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```js
var url  = "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste";
var page = url.split('/');
page = page[page.length-1];

console.log(page.split('?')[0]);
```

Se você quiser pegar os parâmetros:

```js
var url  = "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste";
var page = url.split('/');
page = page[page.length-1];

console.log(page.split('?')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Há várias maneiras.

Podes fazer isso por regex:

```js
var href = "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste";
var match = href.match(/([^\/]+)\?/);
var pagina = match && match[1];

console.log(pagina);
```

Podes fazer isso com slice:

```js
var href = "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste";
var pagina = href.slice(18, href.indexOf('?'));
console.log(pagina);
```

Podes fazer isso com split:

```js
var href = "http://google.com/pagina.atual?origem=teste";
var pagina = href.split('/').pop().split('?').shift();
console.log(pagina);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, fiz de uma forma que você possa alterar facilmente o código.
Espero que te ajude!

```
var url = 'http://google.com/pagina.atual?teste';
url = url.split('/')[3];
if(url.indexOf('?') != -1){
    url = url.split('?')[0];
}
document.write(url);
```

Exemplo : [EXEMPLO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o7z28Lh0/)